# How to disable a button if all of the inputs is empty in asp.net core

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to submit a form. I have a binding dropdown list and an input field. The dropdown list has three input fields. 0 = pending, 1 = accepted, and 2 = denied. I want to store data if the dropdown value is not 0/pending. If the dropdown is changed/ not pending or the comment input field have not empty, then the Save button enables. Otherwise, the save button is disabled.

```js
function success() {
            if (document.getElementById("textsend").value === "") {
                document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div class="row border-top pt-2">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <span>Decision</span><span asp-validation-for="Heating.Status"></span>
                <select asp-for="Heating.Status" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<ApplicationDecision>()" class="form-control">
                    <option></option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <span>Comments</span><span></span>
                <textarea class="form-control " id="textsend" onkeyup="success()" style="height:100px" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row border-top p-2">
            <div class="col">
                <input type="submit" id="button" value="Save" class="btn btn-blueTwo float-right" disabled />
            </div>
        </div>
```

But I can't use the dropdown list to add these conditions. Couldn't you please help me?

Comment: Could you please share your full view along with relevant models snippet?

Comment: Reegarding your `dropdown status` it can be managed well if you could populate the dorpdown value by calling an `ajax get` request.

Comment: Hi @Mizanur did you able to resolve the issue? Let me know if you need any further assistance on it, as said, using `jQuery` it can be resolve easily.

Comment: Awesome, sounds great, however, I have also reolved  following your requirements using `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I solved this problem.

```js
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.save-btn').attr('disabled', true);

            $('#CommentResponse').change(function () {
               
                let cmtData = $("#CommentResponse").val();
               
                if (cmtData !=null ) {
                    $('.save-btn').attr('disabled', false);
                }
                if(cmtData == "")
                {
                    $('.save-btn').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            })
            $('#StatusResponse').change(function () {
                
                let statusData= $(this).val();
                if (statusData != 0) {
                    $('.save-btn').attr('disabled', false);
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.save-btn').attr('disabled', true);
                }
            })

        });
    </script>
```

```html
<div class="row border-top pt-2">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <span>Decision</span><span asp-validation-for="BurnOut.Status"></span>
                    <select asp-for="BurnOut.Status" id="StatusResponse" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<ApplicationDecision>()" class="form-control ">
                        <option></option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <span>Comments</span><span asp-validation-for="BurnOut.Remarks"></span>
                    <textarea class="form-control " id="CommentResponse" asp-for="BurnOut.Remarks" style="height:100px" maxlength="2000"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row border-top p-2">
                <div class="col">
                    <input type="submit"  value="Save" class="btn btn-blueTwo float-right save-btn" />
                </div>
            </div>
```